# TBB parallel_for threadpool

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, tbb

I'm trying to learn a bit about TBB and I have a doubt that I haven't been able to solved it.

Afaik, TBB uses a threadpool so it doesn't need to create threads all the time. If you use tbb::parallel_for, does it use this threadpool or does it create new threads? If it uses the threadpool, how is the threadpool created? There is no need to do any call to create the threadpool or configure it. Does it creates the threadpool on the first parallel invocation?

Comment: Why not use the standard library solution, as in [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with an [ExecutionPolicy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) of `std::execution::parallel_policy`? That's nice and portable.

Comment: Im stuck with c++14. Also, the same question would apply to that case.

Comment: TBB has internal thread pool and it needs some time to create threads on a first tbb's algorithm call (to "warm-up" library). You didn't need to create it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @ntfs.hard. If you post it as an answer, I could mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBB has internal [thread pool](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/topic/290291#comment-1576636) and it needs some time to create threads on a first tbb's algorithm call (to "warm-up" library). You didn't need to create it explicitly. [1](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/topic/290291#comment-1576636) 
 is a quite old post but it has a clue how it working under the hood(or it was some time ago)

Also if you need to specify some limits for threads count or stack size of worker threads for a part of your algorithm you can use [task_scheduler_init](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506296) but it not hard-bounded with a real thread count. Just FYI.